# What is the context for calling someone "bones"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What is the context for using the term "bones" to refer to someone? I have seen that in the original "Star Trek", Kirk calls Dr. McCoy "bones". This word was translated into my native Portuguese as "magro", which means "thin"... and I am not sure if this is the correct translation.

Why does Kirk call Dr. McCoy "bones"?

Comment: Frank Sinatra, reminiscing on TV about his start in show business, quipped that in the early days the fans would say, "Let's go and see ol' bones down at the Paramount". Evidently this was his nickname, one that alluded to fact he was "all skin and bones" at the start of his career. He looked emaciated and in need of plate of pasta!

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/99672/where-did-the-nickname-of-bones-for-mccoy-come-from

Comment: @Gnawme fantastic! now it makes sense. Please convert your comment to an answer, so I can accept.

Comment: It can also mean your are thin and have a lack of muscle.

Comment: Mc Coy: The character's nickname, "Bones", is a play on sawbones, an epithet for physicians  qualified as surgeons. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonard_McCoy

Comment: Possibly worth noting that the Dr. Temperance Brennan character on *Bones* is not a surgeon, but rather an anthropologist.  She receives her nickname due to the fact that she learns about the history of people by studying what remains- generally only their bones.

Comment: It would be farfetched to say this comment is on topic, but I can't resist commenting that English sailors referred to Napoleon as "old boney."

Answer (score 44, accepted):

*Bones* in this context is derived from *[sawbones](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sawbones)*, slang for a physician or surgeon.

Comment: Particularly in a naval context, where amputating a shattered limb was commonplace.  And there are plenty of pseudo-naval behaviours in Star Trek

Comment: ***sawbones (n.)***: 
"surgeon," 1837, slang, from verbal phrase; http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=sawbones

Comment: By the way, in the German dubbed version, his nickname is "Pille" ("pill"), which is a much better fit than the Portuguese version.

Comment: @MaxRied: Because of Mike Piller? Or something else?

Comment: In the movie Star Trek (2009), I think they tried to imply that the nickname Bones came from the line, "The ex-wife took the whole damn planet in the divorce; all I've got left is my bones."  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlphfLO3MYA

Answer (score 13):

Before anaesthetics (and antibiotics) were invented, surgery was often rudimentary for fairly obvious reasons. The reputation of a surgeon tended to be based on how quickly he could perform an amputation (I say "he" advisedly since there were no female surgeons at the time.) This involved little more than making the patient as drunk as possible to dull the pain, getting several assistants to hold him (or her) down, and then sawing through the affected limb as quickly as possible to minimise the agony caused. Robert Liston, a noted Victorian surgeon, was said to be able to amputate a leg in two and a half minutes, and once removed a limb in 28 seconds.

For this reason, as has already been said, surgeons and doctors were often called *sawbones*, and a good one was quick as well as accurate. Doctors were also known as *quacks*, but this term would have been a gross insult to any surgeon.

[Wikipedia: Robert Liston](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Liston)

Answer (score 3):

Actually in the first Star Trek that Abrahms directed, Kirk asked McCoy that question.. his answer was that he had gotten divorced and all he got were the left over "bones" of their marriage. The name stuck.

Comment: If you could site a source that would be great.

Comment: @D.Patrick posted the link in a comment above.

Answer (score 0):

Usually a shortened version of the slang term "sawbones" which referred to the original surgeons of medicine because they used saws to remove damages limbs from patients. A good 'sawbones' could remove a limb in seconds using a hacksaw, alcohol and some strong assisents to hold the patient down.

Comment: Can you provide references to support your answer? :)

Answer (score -2):

"Bones," used in this context, is a 'Nickname.'  Americans are traditionally fond of the usage of Nicknames.